# Indexwise sum of list of lists using rxjava

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a list of array lists. Each list in the main list contains constant number of items. (Say 3 items in each array list). What I want to do is I need to get the indexwise sum of each list as a new List.

for example if my main List contains array lists like

```
       1, 2, 3
       1, 2, 3
       1, 2, 3
```

then my resultant list should be

```
       3, 6, 9
```

and I have to do this with RxJava only. Since I am very new to RxJava I'm confused with which operators I should use. I tried many ways but since those are not working I'm not posting with question. If anyone could suggest a hint or suggestion it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

My source list is

```
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> mainList;
```

and I need a resultant `List<Integer> sumList`

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the main purpose of RxJava but you can do this via zip:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lists.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
}

Flowable<Integer> f = Flowable.zip(lists, a -> {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Object o : a) {
        sum += (Integer)o;
    }
    return sum;
})

// as individual items
f.test()
.assertResult(3, 6, 9);

// as one list
f.toList()
.test()
.assertResult(Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9));
```

Answer (score -1):

1)You should add the following [RxMath](https://github.com/NandagopalR/RxJavaOperatorsExample) dependency in your build.gradle (app level).

```
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
```

2) Use the following code to add sum of integer values from an Array or List.

```
int totalCount =  MathObservable.sumInteger(Observable.just(classesItemList)
                .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<ClassesItem>, Iterable<? extends ClassesItem>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<? extends ClassesItem> call(List<ClassesItem> list) {
                        return list;
                    }
                })
                .map(new Func1<ClassesItem, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer call(ClassesItem classesItem) {
                        return classesItem != null ? classesItem.getStudentsCount() : 0;
                    }
                })).toBlocking().single();
```

3) use the total count wherever you want.